# "Field type ContentTypeIdFieldType is not installed properly" while opeing v4.master page in designer?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, 2007, upgrade

I have upgraded SharePoint 2007 Enterprise to SharePoint 2010 Foundation. After update, I went designer and trying to open V4.master page. it is throwing below error.
I tried all other pages too and having same issue.

I am not able to find contentypeIDFieldType which I can delete.

[image]